# How to use one data field into another case expression in the same query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to use `SNumber` in the second part of `CASE` expression but not sure how to use it?

```
    select    
        PE.EDateTime,
        (case when(PE.EDateTime is not NULL and cast(PE.EDateTime as time) < '12:30') then cast(format(PE.EDateTime,'yyyyMMddhhmm') as varchar(50))+'AM'
             when (PE.ADate is not NULL and cast(PE.ADate as time) < '12:30') then cast(format(PE.ADate,'yyyyMMddhhmm') as varchar(50))+'AM'
             when (PE.EDateTime is not NULL and cast(PE.EDateTime as time) >= '12:30') THEN  cast(format(PE.EDateTime,'yyyyMMddhhmm') as varchar(50))+'PM'
             when  (PE.ADate is not NULL and cast(PE.ADate as time) > '12:30') then cast(format(PE.ADate,'yyyyMMddhhmm') as varchar(50))+'PM'
             else null 
            end) as SNumber,
   
     case 
   when (SNumber like'%AM') then 'AM'
   when SNumber like '%PM') then 'PM'
   else null 
end as [Session],
        Comments   
    from (
        select       
            PE1.RId,
            PE1.ADate,
            PE1.EDateTime
        from (
            select
                RegEId, 
                ADate,
                EDateTime,
                Comments
            from PatEnr
            where PreNumber is not null               
            ) as PE1
        left join Pat PEA 
            on PE1.RegEId = PEA.RegEId   
        left join PBooking PB 
            on PB.RegEId = PE1.RegEId
        ) as PE
```

I want to use `SNumber` here below in the same query but I am not able to use this as this all belongs to one query. Is there any way to use the above in below `CASE`? I want to use something like below.

```
case 
   when (SNumber like'%AM') then 'AM'
   when (SNumber like '%%PM') then 'PM'
   else null 
end as Session,
```

Comment: It may be useful to see the overall requirement in the context of the entire query.  There are potentially a handful of different ways that you could achieve this.  You could put the CASE expression into a scalar-type user-defined function (which makes it easier to reuse in other queries), or you could incorporate the CASE expression into a common-table expression (CTE), that you then SELECT from (and apply your further CASE logic).  Or you could just wrap the existing CASE expression in RIGHT( <case expression>, 2), since that seems to be essentially what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Aside: You might want to consider using `Coalesce( PE.EDateTime, PE.ADate )` to simplify your `case` expression.

Answer (score 2):

Use cross apply to perform your calculation which you can then reuse.

```
select
    SNumber
    , case when SNumber like '%AM%' then 'AM'
    when SNumber like  '%PM%' then 'PM'
    else null end as [Session]
from MyTable PE
cross apply (
values (
    case when(PE.EDateTime is not NULL and cast(PE.EDateTime as time) < '12:30') then cast(format(PE.EDateTime,'yyyyMMddhhmm') as varchar(50))+'AM'
    when (PE.ADate is not NULL and cast(PE.ADate as time) < '12:30') then cast(format(PE.ADate,'yyyyMMddhhmm') as varchar(50))+'AM'
    when (PE.EDateTime is not NULL and cast(PE.EDateTime as time) >= '12:30') THEN  cast(format(PE.EDateTime,'yyyyMMddhhmm') as varchar(50))+'PM'
    when (PE.ADate is not NULL and cast(PE.ADate as time) > '12:30') then cast(format(PE.ADate,'yyyyMMddhhmm') as varchar(50))+'PM'
    else null 
    end
)) x (SNumber)
```

Note: [`contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) doesn't work in that context - its a `where` clause predicate for full-text search, so I've replaced with [`like`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Hi Dale, could you please provide an answer based on the above question. I have modified the question. I am looking forward to your help. Thanks!

Comment: @user10216769 its not cool to completely change your question once you have received an answer. But anyway, the principle is the same, just substitute your query entire "from" query into where I have my "MyTable".